# Load OPENCV into android application

Tags: android, opencv

I am creating an android application and i am using OPENCV for face detection.I have created a new android project using eclipse and now i have to add the OPENCV Face detection(a separate project in eclipse) into the newly created project. I have to call the OPENCV's onCreate method from the new android project's Activity class. I have googled and i am not clear in doing this.Also to run OPENCV code we need to install OPENCV Manager in the device/emulator.

Other way is to include the libraries in the newly created android project which will increase the app size.Which method is better to use? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you copy the necessary part of the Face Detection project into your own new project. That way you will be able to implement whatever additional functionalities keeping the face detection intact. 
And yes, OpenCV manager needs to be installed on the device if you want to load the OpenCV library asynchronously. If you do not like this way then you gonna have to add that library statically to your project which will increase the size of your final apk.
It really depends upon what you think is most probable. I personally prefer to load it asynchronously because it is the faster and easier way.

Comment: Is it possible to have the OPENCV as separate project and link it with the new project i have created without copying?